# Angular passing API response to child component

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, api

I have a "Dashboard" component, and a "Dashboard-InfoBox" child component. 
In my Dashboard component I call a function in my service that returns the API response, and then I create a variable that holds the data that I want and pass it to Dashboard-InfoBox to render it.

The problem is that Dashboard-infobox tries to access the data while it's still not there, which causes errors in my console.

I have tried including *ngIf="marketData['HENRYHUB']", but the ngIf is not rendering it when the data comes.

market.service.ts

```
  getHenryHub() {
    const henryHubCache = this.responseCache.get(this.henryHubURL);
    if(henryHubCache) {
      console.log(henryHubCache);
      return of(henryHubCache);
    }
    const response = this.http.get<EiaResponse>(this.henryHubURL);
    response.subscribe(res => this.responseCache.set(this.henryHubURL, res));
    return response;
  }
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
this.marketData = {} as IDictionary;

    this.marketDataService.getHenryHub().subscribe(res => {
      let henryHub = {
        date: res["series"][0].data[0][0],
        price: res["series"][0].data[0][1].toFixed(2),
        status: res["series"][0].data[0][1] > res["series"][0].data[1][1] ? true : false,
      }
    this.marketData['HENRYHUB'] = henryHub;
    });
```

dashboard-infobox.component.ts

```
  @Input() marketData: any;

        <div *ngIf="marketData" class="tab-wrapper" style="float: right">
    <div class="exchange" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #1e6ec8;">
        <p style="font-weight: 600; margin: auto;">
            Gas/Oil Prices
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="exchange" *ngIf="marketData.BRENT">
        <p style="flex: 0 0 30%; margin-left: 15px;">
            Brent Oil
        </p>
        <img matListAvatar [src]="marketData.BRENT.status ? 'assets/img/up.png' : 'assets/img/down.png'" style="width: 20px" />
        <p style="flex: 0 0 40%; margin-left: 15px;">
            {{ marketData.BRENT.price }} $/Bbl
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ date | date: 'MMM dd' }}
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="exchange" *ngIf="marketData.HENRYHUB">
        <p style="flex: 0 0 30%; margin-left: 15px;">
            Henry Hub
        </p>
        <img matListAvatar [src]="marketData.HENRYHUB.status ? 'assets/img/up.png' : 'assets/img/down.png'" style="width: 20px" />
        <p style="flex: 0 0 40%; margin-left: 15px;">
            {{ marketData.HENRYHUB.price }} $/MMBtu
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ date | date: 'MMM dd' }}
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="exchange" *ngIf="marketData.NBP">
        <p style="flex: 0 0 30%; margin-left: 15px;">
            NBP
        </p>
        <img matListAvatar [src]="marketData.NBP.status ? 'assets/img/up.png' : 'assets/img/down.png'" style="width: 20px" />
        <p style="flex: 0 0 40%; margin-left: 15px;">
            {{ marketData.NBP.price }} $/MMBtu
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ date | date: 'MMM dd' }}
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="exchange" *ngIf="marketData.TTF">
        <p style="flex: 0 0 30%; margin-left: 15px;">
            TTF
        </p>
        <img matListAvatar [src]="marketData.TTF.status ? 'assets/img/up.png' : 'assets/img/down.png'" style="width: 20px" />
        <p style="flex: 0 0 40%; margin-left: 15px;">
            {{ marketData.TTF.price }} $/MMBtu
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ date | date: 'MMM dd' }}
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="exchange" *ngIf="marketData.GASOIL">
        <p style="flex: 0 0 30%; margin-left: 15px;">
            Gas Oil
        </p>
        <img matListAvatar [src]="marketData.GASOIL.status ? 'assets/img/up.png' : 'assets/img/down.png'" style="width: 20px" />
        <p style="flex: 0 0 40%; margin-left: 15px;">
            {{ marketData.GASOIL.price }} $/Mt
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ date | date: 'MMM dd' }}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

I get 4 errors in the console for each of these variables. However on my Dashboard everything shows exactly the way I want it.

Comment: Use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/a4-observable-cache` to get cache for free instead of implementing your own (and duplicate code) over all the observables

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a good solution. I will try to use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dashboard-infobox Component Template, wrap the div with an `*ngIf` the way you were doing before you edited the question.

Plus, you should be good with just one `img` tag instead of two. You're showing them conditionally anyway.

Here, give this a try:

```
<div class="exchange" *ngIf="marketData.HENRYHUB">
  <p style="flex: 0 0 30%; margin-left: 15px;">
    Henry Hub
  </p>
  <img 
    matListAvatar 
    [src]="marketData.HENRYHUB.status ? 'assets/img/up.png' : 'assets/img/down.png'" 
    style="width: 20px" />
  <p style="flex: 0 0 40%; margin-left: 15px;">
    {{ marketData.HENRYHUB.price }} $/MMBtu
  </p>
  <p>
    {{ date | date: 'MMM dd' }}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the modifications. That actually worked when I did it for HENRYHUB. However, when I changed all div's to be similar to that, none were rendered. I have edited the post to include all of them above.

Comment: Also: If I navigate with the router to another link, and then go back to Dashboard, everthing is rendered fine, and shows exactly what I want with no errors.

Comment: It should work ideally. Could setting just `HENRYHUB` in your `subscribe` block in the parent component be the reason? Just sayin! If not, would you mind creating a minimal StackBlitz for me that replicates this issue?

Comment: I made a stackblitz, and it works perfectly. This is the weirdest thing I've seen, there's 5 divs, each with an *ngIf, on the stackblitz they worked perfectly, and each of them showed when the data came. However, when i'm serving my project it doesn't show anything, and if I switch links in the router and go back, it will show them. And even more weird, If I remove 1 *ngIf from 1 of the DIVS, it will work. However I will get the errors for that DIV in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your ng-if against the marketData variable which you initialized as {} (thats not null)

```
<div class="exchange" *ngIf="markedData && marketData !== {}">
      <p style="flex: 0 0 30%; margin-left: 15px;">
          Henry Hub
      </p>
      <img *ngIf="marketData['HENRYHUB'].status" matListAvatar 
        [src]="'assets/img/up.png'" 
        style="width: 20px"
        />
      <img *ngIf="!marketData['HENRYHUB'].status" matListAvatar 
        [src]="'assets/img/down.png'" 
        style="width: 20px"
        />
      <p style="flex: 0 0 40%; margin-left: 15px;">
      {{ marketData['HENRYHUB'].price }} $/MMBtu
      </p>
      <p>
      {{ date | date: 'MMM dd' }}
      </p>
    </div>
```

You have errors because when Angular firsts checks the variable is null, then the changeDetection works and pass the value to your child, so everything renders

Comment: The way you've set the `*ngIf`, I'm pretty sure it would always result in `true`.